# como hacer una consulta con MAX(count) y otro atributo

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Quiero hacer una consulta que en teoria ( y mal a efectos practicos) seria algo asi

```
select A,MAX(COUNT(B)) from Tabla group by A;
```

Sin embargo se que esto no funciona. Para que MAX(count(op)) funcione tendria que ponerlo solo, es decir quedaria algo como esto:

```
select MAX(COUNT(OP)) from Tabla group by A;
```

Sin embargo requierdo del atributo A asociado al MAX(...).

Como podria hacerlo ?, haciendo algo analogo a lo primero me salta el siguiente error:

```
 ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como te comenta el error, tienes dos funciones de grupo anidadas.

No necesitas hacer dos consultas anidadas, puedes agrupar contando:

```
select A, COUNT(B) from tabla group by A;
```

y el resultado lo ordenas:

```
select A, COUNT(B) as cantidad from tabla group by A order by cantidad;
```

y te quedas sólo con el primero:

```
select A, COUNT(B) as cantidad 
from tabla 
group by A 
order by cantidad desc
fetch first row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa a la propuesta de Pablo podría ser:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT A, 
         COUNT(B) Cant
         FROM tabla
         GROUP BY A
 )
 SELECT *
        FROM CTE T1
        WHERE CANT = (SELECT MAX(CANT) FROM CTE)
;
```

Es un poco más compleja, pero tiene dos puntos interesantes:

- Es una solución "SQL pura", debiera ser compatible con casi cualquier base de datos, que al menos implemente "common table expresion"
- En caso que tuvieras más de un `A` con el mismo máximo esta consulta te retornará todos estos.